# Nginx 401 error page not showing

Tags: nginx

I am trying to make my authentication so that if a user repeatedly hits cancel on the login-pw prompt..it will not go back to the page they are trying to access, but to a page I specify. Right now if the user keeps hitting cancel on the prompt they can see tidbits of the page. If they do this they need to be redirected to my site. index.html

Here is my code

```
                location /pages/club/ {
                    auth_basic "Restricted";
                    auth_basic_user_file  /home/the/site/directory/page/works/.htpasswd;
                    error_page 401  /index.html;
            }
```

This is not making a difference. I've read over the documentation and tried a number of different things.

Answer (score 0):

That is not how auth basic works. You can't redirect the 401 response in this manner and users can click "cancel" infinitely if they want.

If they are seeing the page after hitting "cancel", then they is something wrong with your setup and this is what needs looking into.

Answer (score 0):

If the user is seeing 'tidbits' of the page that implies to me that it isn't actually protected by simple authorization...but rather some form of javascript.